# AJAX request isn't recognized as such

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have a list of items which can be searched and the page has pagination. When a search query is entered the partial view gets loaded correctly (AJAX). However, when you use the pagination, it fires a non-ajax request (entire page gets reloaded and no XmlHttpRequest flag in the header).

What causes this?

```
$(function () {
 // Adds Ajax to pagination of search results
    var getPage = function () {
        var $a = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $a.attr("href"),
            type: "get",
            data: $("form").serialize() 
        };

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $a.parents("div.pagedlist").attr("data-nn-target");
            var $newHtml = $(data);
            $target.html($newHtml);
            $newHtml.effect("highlight");
        });

        // Prevent default action
        return false;
    };

    $(".main-content").on("click", ".pagedlist a", getPage);
 });

<form method="GET" action='@Url.Action("Index", "Show")' data-nn-ajax="true" data-nn-target="#contentlist" class="form-search">
    <div class="input-append mysearch">
        <input type="search" class="span5 search-query" name="query" data-nn-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutoComplete")" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="contentlist">
    <table></table> // content
    <div class="pagedlist" data-nn-target="#contentlist">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
    </div>
</div>
```

According to the tutorial, this line of code should've solved the issue where you can't use the pagination for a resultset.

`data: $("form").serialize()`

```
 public ActionResult Index(string query = "", int page = 1) {
        IPagedList<ShowViewModel> model;

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
            model = ViewModelFactory.Instance.CreateShowViewModels(_showRepository.GetShows()
                                                                                       .Where(
                                                                                           x =>
                                                                                           x.Title.ToLower()
                                                                                            .Contains(
                                                                                                query.ToLower())))
                                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.LatestRelease).ToList().ToPagedList(page, 15);
            ViewBag.Search = query;
            return PartialView("_Shows", model);
        }

        model = ViewModelFactory.Instance.CreateShowViewModels(_showRepository.GetShows()).OrderByDescending(x => x.LatestRelease).ToList().ToPagedList(page, 15);
        ViewBag.Search = null;
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint at both the `View` and the `PartialView` call, it hits the `View` whenever I use pagination (and thus causing all data to be displayed each time). Why aren't my requests seen as AJAX ones?

Comment: Are you using PagedList from this project? https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Comment: After the closing `});` for the `document.ready` event handler, what's the extra `}` for?

Comment: @Jasper: I've removed it, it was a typo while copying parts of the file.

Comment: Have you verified that `getPage` is being called when you click on a link and that there are no JavaScript errors preventing the default action from happening for the pagination links?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the javascript code is supposed to throw away the normal paging request and send an ajax one instead, no?

Since this is how it's done in the tutorial (http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=6&course=mvc4-building), I'm assuming it is supposed to work.

Comment: Also, I don't see a `main-content` in your posted markup; maybe the `.main-content` selector isn't matching anything.

Comment: Is this the correct for checking if getPage is called: Place `Console.log("test")` in the getPage method and look at the console tab in the chrome dev tools? If so: I don't see it appear.

`main-content` is the general wrapper in the layout view, it's there. When I enable 'log XmlHttpRequests' in the console, it reloads the console so there is no Ajax request sent.

Comment: Try `console.log` (lowercase console) or setting a breakpoint. I'm not familiar with `Console` unless you have a separate library loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32586/discussion-between-jacob-and-jeroen-vannevel)

Comment: I have another problem. pagination link is still sent directly to the browser even after Ajax request is sent. But this does not happen in the video. i.e. When I click next page, first an ajax request page=2&searchTerm=Res2 is sent, then non ajax get is sent with page=2 and whole page is replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `.main-content` is a true ancestor of your pagination links; otherwise, the event delgation `$(".main-content").on("click", ".pagedlist a", getPage)` won't work.

**Update**:

Follow-up issue. this:

```
var $target = $a.parents("div.pagedlist").attr("data-nn-target");
```

...should be this instead:

```
var $target = $($a.parents("div.pagedlist").attr("data-nn-target"));
```

This is because `attr("data-nn-target")` will just give you the *selector*, not a jQuery object using that selector.