# Ajax request is overriden by onClick request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

I am following [Building Applications with ASP.NET MVC 4](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=6&course=mvc4-building) tutorial. But for me ajax request `/?page=2&searchTerm=Res2` is overridden by another direct non-ajax request `/?page=2` which is actually `href` of the page link. This as a result replaces whole page with new data.

While tutorial goes smoothly and click sends only an Ajax request to server.

```
$(function () {
    var ajaxSubmit = function () {
        var $form = $(this);

        var options = {
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: $form.serialize()
        }

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
            var $effectHtml = $(data);

            $target.replaceWith($effectHtml);
            $effectHtml.effect("highlight");
        });

        return false;
    }

    var submitAutoCompleteForm = function (event, ui) {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.val(ui.item.label);

        $input.parents("form:first").submit();
    }

    var createAutoComplete = function () {
        var $input = $(this);

        var options = {
            source: $input.attr("data-otf-autocomplete"),
            select: submitAutoCompleteForm
        }

        $input.autocomplete(options);
    }

    var getPage = function () {
        var $a = $(this);
        $a.attr("disabled", true);

        var options = {
            url: $a.attr("href"),
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            type: "get"
        }

        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("data-otf-target");
            $(target).replaceWith(data);
        });
    }

    $("form[data-otf-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxSubmit);
    $("input[data-otf-autocomplete]").each(createAutoComplete);
    $(".body-content").on("click", ".pagedList a", getPage);
})
```

Div for results

```
<div id="restaurantList">
    <div class="pagedList" data-otf-target="#restaurantList">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
    </div>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>@item.City, @item.Country</div>
            <div>@item.CountOfReviews</div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

and layout

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369597/ajax-request-isnt-recognized-as-such) about the same pagination tutorial but that does not address this problem.

Comment: replace  this `var ajaxSubmit = function () {` with  `var ajaxSubmit = function (e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @NaeemShaikh it works on my first click only. On next click it loads a new page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using AJAX to retrieve data on submit of the form and click of the a, you need to prevent the default action of those events by using `preventDefault()`. Try this:

```
var ajaxSubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // rest of your code...
}

var getPage = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // rest of your code...
}
```